# Mongo vs Couch in a specific use case

Tags: mongodb, couchdb

My use case is this: Currently, in Couch I've created views by emitting mapreduce keys that are programmatically calculated based on the fields of the documents. For example, a document always has fields a, b, c, each having a numeric value, and I want to index their sum without having to store it explicitly as another field. Couch's indexes(views) is a perfect fit for that because I can emit whatever I want. So in my use case I am emitting (a+b+c, _id). Updates of the fields are rare compared to the inserts of new ones, but they do occur. The whole point of this is that the biggest part of querying of my app is range or single queries on such derived indexes. Note that I dont need the reduce part. Can I achieve this with mongo? I ve read the docs but I cant find something about it. Any ideas? The reason I want to do it in mongo is that I would like to try it in a real scenario and compare the performance with that of couch for my use case.

Comment: "Can't find anything about it?" What's it? MongoDB has MapReduce, but it doesn't work the same as CouchDB views. It also has an aggregation framework, but that is "live" and isn't precomputed.

Comment: Yes, I cant find anything about using map part of mapreduce as index

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MongoDB does have MapReduce, but the results are not stored and updated incrementally, thus it is not a good fit for what you want to do. You would have to store a sum field in the document and update it yourself when the summands get updated.